# Define a function on two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathbb N$ be the set of natural numbers $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ and $\mathbb Z$ be the set of integers $\{0,1,-1,2,-2,\dots\}$. Define a function $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ on $ \mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$. Define also a function $g(x) = 2x + 1$ on $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$. Determine whether these functions are one-to-one and/or on-to. And, what about $f(g(x))$?

My question is what is meant by define a function on $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$. Is it implied from this description which one of these input sets is the domain?

Comment: I think it actually means to define *two* functions.  First take $f$ to be the function $f:N\to N$ for which $f(n) = n^2 +1$, and answer the questions.  Then take $f$ to be the function $f:Z\to Z$ for which $f(z) = z^2+1$ and answer the questions again. But it is very confusingly phrased.

Comment: Thanks @MJD, that did not occur to me and the question makes far more sense now.